# Why can't PHP create a directory with 777 permissions?

Tags: php, mkdir

I'm trying to create a directory on my server using PHP with the command:

```
mkdir("test", 0777);
```

But it doesn't give full permissions, only these:

```
rwxr-xr-x
```

Answer (score 182, accepted):

The mode is modified by your current `umask`, which is `022` in this case.

The way the `umask` works is a subtractive one. You take the initial permission given to `mkdir` and subtract the `umask` to get the *actual* permission:

```
  0777
- 0022
======
  0755 = rwxr-xr-x.
```

If you don't want this to happen, you need to set your `umask` temporarily to zero so it has no effect. You can do this with the following snippet:

```
$oldmask = umask(0);
mkdir("test", 0777);
umask($oldmask);
```

The first line changes the `umask` to zero while storing the previous one into `$oldmask`. The second line makes the directory using the desired permissions and (now irrelevant) `umask`. The third line restores the `umask` to what it was originally.

See the PHP doco for [umask](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) and [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) for more details.

Answer (score 14):

The creation of files and directories is affected by the setting of umask. You can create files with a particular set of permissions by manipulating umask as follows :-

```
$old = umask(0);
mkdir("test", 0777);
umask($old);
```

Answer (score 10):

Avoid using this function in multithreaded webservers. It is better to change the file permissions with chmod() after creating the file.

**Example:**

```
$dir = "test";
$permit = 0777;

mkdir($dir);
chmod($dir, $permit);
```

Answer (score 4):

For those who tried

`mkdir('path', 777);`

and it did not work.

It is because, apparently, the 0 preceding the file mode is very important which tells chmod to interpret the passed number as an Octal instead of a decimal.

[Reference](http://digitalfortress.tech/php/difference-file-mode-0777-vs-777/)

Ps. This is not a solution to the question but only an add-on to the accepted anwser

Comment: To be clear, `chmod` does not do any special interpreting... PHP parses 0xxx as an octal notation, a feature that works everywhere, even in regular functions: `echo max(050, 24); // echos 40, which is what 050 is`

Answer (score 2):

Probably, your [umask](http://linux.die.net/man/2/umask) is set to exclude those

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have to use the following way for centos7, which solved the problem

```
$oldmask = umask(000);//it will set the new umask and returns the old one 
mkdir("test", 0777);
umask($oldmask);//reset the old umask
```

More details can be found at
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php