# mkdir not obeying permission parameter

Tags: php, linux

I am using mkdir in a php script to make file3 in directory `/file/file2/file3`. I use permission 777 but the file always looks like `dr----x--t 2 admin admin 4096 Jul  1 19:26 file3` once it is made. I am running Centos 5 64bit. file2 is permission `drwxrwxrwx 16 root root 4096 Jul  1 19:26 file2` already. Anyone have any ideas why this is?

```
mkdir("/file1/file2/file3",777);
```

Comment: The default mkdir mode is 777, have you tried making the directory then doing PHPs chmod command?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to use `777` *octal,* not decimal:

```
mkdir ("/file1/file2/file3", 0777);
```

`777` decimal turns out to be `1411` octal which will give you the bitmask `1 100 001 001` which is why you're getting those "strange" permissions. The standard set (last three segments) gives you `r----x--x` and the first segment modifies the world permissions to `t` (the sticky bit).

Also keep in mind that `mkdir` is subject to your `umask` setting and may not give you the permissions you ask for (your `umask` setting gets "removed" from the permissions you ask for to give you the actual permissions). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997641/why-cant-php-create-a-directory-with-777-permissions/3997671#3997671) for details, including how to avoid the problem.

You're better off using `mkdir` to create the directory then `chmod` (which *isn't* affected by your `umask` setting) to change the permissions.

Answer (score 3):

`mkdir()` is also affected by the current [`umask()`](http://php.net/umask), See example #1

```
$old = umask(0);
chmod("/path/some_dir/some_file.txt", 0755);
umask($old);
```

Also have a look at the note

> **Note:**
>
> Avoid using this function in multithreaded webservers. It is better to change the file permissions with chmod() after creating the file. Using umask() can lead to unexpected behavior of concurrently running scripts and the webserver itself because they all use the same umask.

A little bit background can be found at [Wikipedia: umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask)

Answer (score 1):

I've run into issues with this before and ended up working around it using.

```
chmod ("/file1/file2/file3",777)
```

Never solved the actual issue though...

Comment: @Scarface, the chmod didn't work because it's still using _decimal_ 777. It would if ti used 0777 (octal) instead.