# PHP create directory with 777 permission in Windows

Tags: php, linux, windows, permissions

I have read this:-
[Why can't PHP create a directory with 777 permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997641/why-cant-php-create-a-directory-with-777-permissions)

and I can see a new folder being created by applying the following:-

```
// Desired folder structure
$structure = "../../../".$flash_dir."HELLO";

// To create the nested structure, the $recursive parameter 
// to mkdir() must be specified.

    $oldmask = umask(0);
    mkdir($structure, 0777);
    umask($oldmask);
```

when viewing the file permission of HELLO with DreamWeaver, it is 777. However, I suspect it is a Linux 0777 rather than a Windows 777, therefore I still cannot upload things to HELLO.

Will there be any alternative method to create a directory with windows 777? Thanks!

PS. when I manual create a new directory and right click it to set 777, it works perfectly, so I really think it's related to Linux vs Windows~

Comment: If on linux you should also check the files owner and group, an upload script owned by root (because up uploaded it or created it as root) but run as www-data cannot upload files owned by a directory created by www-data. enable `error_reporting_(E_ALL);`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I always thought that root can read & write whatever & whereever it wants.

Comment: @micha unless apache is running as root then it wont own the file. Scripts are run by the apache process not by who owns them

Comment: if you are creating a directory with PHP its owned by the same user who owns the apache process. Now this user can create file on that folder. There should not be any permission problem.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im seems safemode is on :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`0777` is exactly the same thing as `777`**

But I still can't say what the problem is. I would try to chmod it again after you've created it.

```
$oldmask = umask(0);
chmod($structure, 0777);
umask($oldmask);
```

Comment: I further added the above script, but it still shows:-
Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid is 10400 is not allowed to access /var/www/web92/web/friends/uploads/flash/JJJ owned by uid 48 in /var/www/web92/web/friends/cms/modules/media_upload/process.php on line 96

Comment: SAFE MODE = Damn out of luck, ask your host to turn it off or your off.