# Creating writable directory with mkdir in PHP

Tags: php, permissions, mkdir

I have this code to create recursive directories:

```
define('_PATH', '/www/virtual/user/galleries');
$gallery_path = "/".intval($gallery['id']);

if(!is_dir(_PATH.$gallery_path))
    mkdir(_PATH.$gallery_path, 0777, false);
```

I made the parent directory ('galleries') writable (0777).
I can confirm that the directory is created. However, it is NOT created with 0777 permissions, but with 0755! I have no explanation for this. :-(

Comment: Your code show that you are attempt to create a directory when NOT exist. What if the directory already exist? It just inherit the existing mod.

Comment: probably this is useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997641/why-cant-php-create-a-directory-with-777-permissions

Comment: Thanks, tearsdontfalls, it looks like umask is the problem.