# Permissions issues on Symfony2 filesystem with mkdir function

Tags: php, symfony

I use the Mkdir function of symfony2 filesystem's class.
The doc (http://symfony.com/fr/doc/2.3/components/filesystem.html#mkdir) says that the directory must be created with 777 permission by default.

But when I use this function in my command, the directory is well created but with 755 permission. I launch my command in root...

What is the problem ?

Think's and sorry for my bad english

Comment: I have found the response to my question here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997641/why-cant-php-create-a-directory-with-777-permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add **umask(0000);** in your app_dev.php or app.php file.

Make sure that you have specified the right directory owner in your cas **www-data**

enjoy !!

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in the permissions as the first argument to the mkdir function

```
->mkdir('/some/directory', 0777);
```

Comment: Same result,
I have also tried to add this line after mkdir but without success :
$fs->chmod($this->upload_root_dir.'/'.$args['identifier'],0777,true);