# Set File permission when creating directory

Tags: php, vtiger, directory-permissions

I have a script that stores files into a directory. The function creates a new directory every 7 days based on the current date (2018>March>week1,2,3, etc.). It works fantastically, but I need to set the directory permissions to 777 otherwise I run into issues. See the code below.

```php
static function initStorageFileDirectory() {
    $filepath = 'storage/';

    $year  = date('Y');
    $month = date('F');
    $day   = date('j');
    $week  = '';
    $mode = 0777;

    if (!is_dir($filepath . $year)) {
        //create new folder
        mkdir($filepath[$mode] . $year);
    }

    if (!is_dir($filepath . $year . "/" . $month)) {
        //create new folder
        mkdir($filepath[$mode] . "$year/$month");
    }

    if ($day > 0 && $day <= 7)
        $week = 'week1';
    elseif ($day > 7 && $day <= 14)
        $week = 'week2';
    elseif ($day > 14 && $day <= 21)
        $week = 'week3';
    elseif ($day > 21 && $day <= 28)
        $week = 'week4';
    else
        $week = 'week5';

    if (!is_dir($filepath . $year . "/" . $month . "/" . $week)) {
        //create new folder
        mkdir($filepath[$mode] . "$year/$month/$week");
    }

    $filepath = $filepath . $year . "/" . $month . "/" . $week . "/";

    return $filepath;
}
```

As you can see, I set $mode. This probably isn't the best way to do this: with the [$mode] inserted it fails to create the directory altogether, but if I remove that bit of code from the mkdir($filepath.... it works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mkdir($filepath[$mode] . $year);
```

This doesn't do what you think it does. It takes the character at index `$mode` from `$filepath`, appends `$year` to it, and creates a directory at the result (without explicitly setting permissions). Since `$filepath` doesn't have 512 characters in it (`0777` is 511 in octal), `$filepath[$mode]` returns an empty string (with an "Uninitialized string offset" notice) and `mkdir` tries to create a directory at `$year`.

`mkdir` takes multiple arguments, the second of which is the mode:

```
mkdir($filepath . $year, $mode);
```

But [`mkdir`'s default mode is `0777`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php#refsect1-function.mkdir-parameters), so if the directory permissions end up being different, [your `umask` is getting in the way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3997641/9029328). You can [set your `umask` to allow `0777` permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3997641/9029328), but it's easier and (possibly) safer to [`chmod`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) the directory after creating it:

```
mkdir($filepath . $year);
chmod($filepath . $year, $mode);
```

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try and report back. does seem like a safer option to chmod the file.

Answer (score 0):

The storage folder should be writable by apache.

Either you can set permission to 777 or transfer the folder ownership to apache. ie, chown to apache user

in ubuntu chown -R www-data:www-data storage/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `shell_exec` php function:

```
shell_exec('chmod -R 777 storage/');
shell_exec('chown -R www-data:www-data storage/');
```