# PHP mkdir is not setting permissions correctly

Tags: php, permissions, mkdir

I am using mkdir in PHP to create a directory if it doesn't exist. However it seems to be failing to set the write part of the permissions.

```
mkdir('/path/to/directory/', 0775, true);
```

Looking at this us ls -l in shell shows that the directory has **drwxr-xr-x** the write permissions for group have not been set.

Even if I try to set 0777 permissions the write is not set for both group and everyone.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: do you have [umask](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html) configured?

Comment: No I wasn't aware of umask, setting umask(0) has worked. Thanks!

Comment: Also, does your file system support traditional unix permissions? The mode parameter probably will not work on nfts and, according to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php#refsect1-function.mkdir-parameters) is ignored on windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't PHP create a directory with 777 permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997641/why-cant-php-create-a-directory-with-777-permissions)